# How do i do POST in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following is my controller code and the view code . The view displays a list of games and i would like to add a game to the existing table in the same view. I'm having some issues with the post proceeding. Any suggestions or could anyone point out what I might me doing wrong?

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /games
  def index
    @games = []
    client = Games::Client.new
    @games =client.get_games
    if @games.blank?
      render_404
    end  
    if params[:name]
      client.create_games params[:name] 
    end
  end
end


%nav.navigation-bar.clearfix{:role => "navigation"}
  %h3.reader-details Game tools
  %a.home{:href => root_path, :role => "link", :title => "Home"}Home
%body
  %section.form
    %form.standard{:action => "/games", :method => "post"}
      %input{type: 'text', name: 'name', class: 'text'}
      %input.primary-action{type: 'submit', value: 'Add', class: 'button'}
  .content
    - if @games.present?
      %table.games
        %thead
          %tr
            %th type
            %th id            
        %tbody
          - @games.each do |game|
            %tr
              %td= game['type']
              %td= game['id']

         %a= link_to "Back", root_path
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `create` action defined. When you create the RESTful routes for a resource, the POST to `/games` doesn't look for the `index` action, it look for the `create` action.

Scaffolding your resource is a good way to see what Rails wants you to do.

`rails g scaffold game name:string`

This will create your RESTful routes and it will create the actions in your controller that correspond to them. Note, you may want to scrap what you have before attempting a scaffold, or the scaffold might not create everything that's needed. Save your view code to a temporary file if you want to paste it back in afterward.

Here's more or less how I'd go about it:

```
# View
= form_for Game.new do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.submit 'Add'

# Controller
  def create
    if Game.create(params[:game])
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:notice] = "There was a problem creating your new game"
      render :action => 'index'
    end
  end

# Routes
  resources :games
```